# Scheduled task running powershell script with SendKeys and getting Access is denied

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that runs a power shell console window with script (script is always runned from machine that has that scheduled task, so there is no remote task calling) that contains:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');
```

Problem is when I'm logged (remotely or locally) it runs smoothly (power shell console opens, procedure runs, key is pressed and procedure completes), but when I log off script is throwing exception in power shell console window:

```
Exception calling "SendWait" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"
At C:\Testing\Powershell\PageFeature.ps1:4 char:2
+  [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception
```

I set task to run with my credentials even when I log off, and still getting messages in the console window.

What could be the root problem of this?

Comment: I think sendkeys need an active user session

Comment: Sendkeys sends window messages, if your session isn't active it has nothing to send to, why are you trying to send keys into the ether? there's another way to achieve your end goal i'd assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe just try:

```
$obj = new-object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$obj.SendKeys("~")
```

Comment: Well is presses key but i think it misses open power shell console window, can this be attached to certain process??

Comment: why do you want to use presKey, can you send the full script and what you want to achieve ?
IMO press key works only in interactive session.

Comment: Well i need to press key else script will not finish.

Comment: Wojtek, it's hard to help without information how scripts behaves, and code. if you just need to close app by pressing any key maybe it's worth to kill the process instead ?